# How to track user origins in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm currently developing a feature that tracks the origins of users that signup/login to my website, from both social media or organic search.

A simple solution would be to use `utm_source` to trace user origins, however it does not fulfill my requirements because it does not work if a user visits the site via organic search, eg. from google.

Is there any other solutions or implementations to track the origin of users that visit our website that provide a wider and more general coverage, ie including from organic searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Ahoy would be great for tracking your page usage, it seems inadequate at tracking where the view came from, you could use either Google Analytics for a solely statistics page, or look into tracking at HTTP-headers in combination with `utm_source`.

In Rails you'd look at the request-headers by using `request`-object, as linked below.
EDIT: That'd be under request.headers.

**Sources:**

- [Rails Documentation - ActionDispatch::Request](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html)
- [Wikipedia: HTTP Referer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer)
- [Webmasters: How to get keywords from Google HTTP referrer?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59794/how-to-get-keywords-from-google-http-referrer)